# Self-hosted WCF service fails with SqlConnection

Tags: c#, wcf, sqlconnection

I'm on a dev pc that does not have admin rights. I'm self-hosting (console) a `WCF service` and using the service with a `WPF` app from the same machine.

The service has method Foo:

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
public FooResult Foo()
{ 
   using(var conn = new SqlConnection())  // exception happens on this line!
   {
      // database access
   }
}
```

Foo accesses a database, but it crashes even before it gets to data access code. It fails at newing up an instance of SqlConnection with following exception:

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory' threw an exception. -->
>   INNER --> The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters' threw an exception. -->
>   INNER --> Requested registry access is not allowed.

I'm sure that db connection string is correct and available for the service instance. My question is: **Is this exception caused by not running the service as an admin?**

Comment: Any chance your company will grant you admin rights on your local box?  My company generally has a very restricted policy on employees machines, but the devs have admin rights on their local boxes for precisely these kinds of reasons.

Comment: Yeah!! Make sure your application is running under elevated privilege. Simply "Run it as Administrator".

Comment: Tim: nope, ain't possible.